# How to instance a constructor with dynamic argument in a responsible DI way

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, nestjs, dto

I'm trying to instance a service with arguments when using the payload received. Ideally I'd like to do this in a more controlled DI responsible way but not sure of the correct approach. Ref code:

```
// inside controller
public async handleRequest(
  @Body() requestDto: RequestDTO
): Promise<void> {
  this.newService = new NewService(
    API_KEYS.get(requestDto.address.country)
  );
  
  await this.newService.triggerBoarding(requestDto);
}
```

This means the service I use in my NewService also has to know about the argument:

```
constructor(apiKey: string) {
  this.outletService = new OutletService(apiKey);
}
```

Would this be a case for lazy loading and using moduleRef?